# specifying image name (using play.db.jpa.blob) using play framework 1.+

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

I am using play framework 1.2+ - I can save an image to disk using play.db.jpa.blob - I am wondering if I can specify the file name using this - if not, I'll just end up using regular File.

```
    //File photo;
testImage.photoFileName = photo.getName();
testImage.photo = new Blob();

        testImage.photo.set(new FileInputStream(photo),  MimeTypes.getContentType(photo.getName()));
```

any helpful suggestions will be welcome.  The file name on the OS is using a UUID - the getName on the File returns the actual name specified for the file - I need to specify the file name for the file so that I can read it from the directory later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

used the javax.imageio.ImageIO.write call (passing in a BufferedImage, file type (png/jpeg etc.) & directory location of file (with the desired file name).